# CSRF token mismatch while uploading image using ajax in CakePHP 3.6

Tags: ajax, cakephp-3.0

I have tried

```
  class UsersController extends AppController
  {
      public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
      {
        $this->getEventManager()->off($this->Csrf);
      } 
   public function ajaxEdit($id = null)
   {
     $this->autoRender = false;

    debug($id);

    debug($this->request->getData());
   }
```

And I am using ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#user-profile').change(function(){
    $('.loader-body').show();
    var form = $('#user-profile-image')[0];
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    var tutorial_id = $('#user-file-id').val();
    $.ajax({
        url :"/users/ajax-edit/"+tutorial_id,
        method:"POST",
        data:formData,
        contentType:false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success:function(data){
            let parseData = $.parseJSON(data);
            if (parseData.status === true) {
                location.reload();
                var value = parseData.url;
                console.log(value);
            } else {
                alert(parseData.message);
            }
        }
      });
    });
   });
```

I have followed help from these links

1. [CakePHP ajax CSRF token mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33918745/cakephp-ajax-csrf-token-mismatch/40603563)

2 https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/csrf.html

Getting **CSRF token mismatch** (see attached image)

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsVZu.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if your are using POST method in your ajax call then you should send tutorial_id as data instead of sending it in the url.

You can resolve this by sending you CSRF token through a special X-CSRF-Token header in your ajax call.
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/csrf.html

```
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('[name="_csrfToken"]').val());
},
```

**OR**

You can disable CSRF component[**Not recommended by the Cakephp**] for your ajax action like:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
     if (in_array($this->request->action, ['ajaxEdit'])) {
         $this->eventManager()->off($this->Csrf);
     }
 }
```